Evaluate string as Lua expression or chunk?
tl;dr; is there a simple way to evaluate a string as either a Lua chunk or a Lua expression without having to first manually figure out which it is?

I'm using the Lua C API (i.e. luaL_dostring) to evaluate externally supplied strings for there side effects and I have it almost working. The remaining issue is that luaL_dostring assumes that it's provided with a chunk (which I want to support in some complex cases) that assumption is causing issues in simple cases with expressions that are more complicated than a simple function call:
Examples:

Fn() works
Fn() and Thing() FAILS
if Fn() then Thing() end works
Fn1() and Fn2() and Fn3() FAILS
if Fn1() and Fn2() and Fn3() then ; end works
if Fn1() and Fn2() then Fn3() end works
return Fn1() and Fn2() and Fn3() works

I could reasonably require the use of #3 in place of #2, but in more complicated but common case of wanting to evaluate a sequence of function calls up to the first that returns false things become more complicated (e.g. #4 becomes one of #5 thought #7) and/or quickly diverge from "it does what it says on the tin" (the expression is evaluated for it's side effects so requiring "returning" something is an unwanted distraction for most users).

After a bit of playing around, I've been able to find string manglings that allows each of those to work, but no one thing that makes all of the above work.

Is the simple trick of "try loading as a chunk, if that fails, prepend return  and try again" not sufficient?

Do what the Lua command line interpreter does: try it as is first; if it fails, prepend "return " and try again. See https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lua.c.html#loadline

I might end up parsing it twice, but I'm still holding out hope for something a bit more principled.

If all you are concerned with is that it is possible to have the value be a block, inspecting the lua syntax will reveal a block can be converted to an expression by wrapping it in a function definition:
return (function() print "hello"; print "world"; return 1; end)()
If what you want is to know whether a string should be interpreted in as a block or expression without parsing it first, that is not really possible, since expressions can contain blocks and blocks can contain expressions, and it may require infinite lookahead to determine which is which.
For example:
some_really_long_function_name() is a valid chunk, while some_really_long_function_name() + 1 is not.  however, some_really_long_function_name(2+2) is a valid expression.
The only theoretical way to achieve what you want without parsing the expression twice would be to write a parser that parses a superset of lua syntax in which an expression is also a valid statement, however such a parser would have to be capable of unbounded token lookahead to disambiguate certain inputs (eg. in the case of a function call with a lot of arguments followed by either a binary operator or a semicolon), so it would not necessarily be any faster than just parsing the string twice.

It seems that while a value can be turned into a block via a function literal, an expression doesn't work: https://onecompiler.com/lua/42cfjp9yd

i think you misread the answer?  a closure can turn a block into an expression, not the other way around.  if you want to turn an expression into a block, prepend it with return .
